# Tried updating an array through an userinput (adding to array) , however it just replaces the last value

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm tasked to do this mock programe where the user is 1st required to create an array then subsequently can insert value to the array until it reaches it limit of 10.
I'm unsure as to why when i tried inserting whereby i'm supposed to insert a value into the existing array called ar it just replaces the last position of the array instead of appending the value into the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

void initialize(int *size, int ar[]);
void insertArray(int max, int *size, int ar[], int num);
void displayArray(int size, int ar[]);

int main()
{
    int option = 0;
    int num, ar[MAX], size = 0;

    printf("Please select an option: \n");
    printf("(1) Create array \n");
    printf("(2) Insert an integer \n");
    printf("(3) Display array \n");
    printf("(4) Quit \n");
    do {
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            initialize(&size, ar);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter an integer: \n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            insertArray(MAX, &size, ar, num);
            break;
        case 3:
            displayArray(size, ar);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (option < 4);
    return 0;
}
void displayArray(int size, int ar[])
{
    int i;
    int number = size + 1;
    printf("The %d numbers in the array: \n", number);
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void initialize(int *size, int ar[])
{
    int total, i, num;
    printf("Enter the total number of integers (MAX=%d): \n", MAX);
    scanf("%d", &total);
    (*size) = 0;
    printf("Enter the integers: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        *size = i;
        insertArray(MAX, size, ar, num);
    }
}

void insertArray(int max, int *size, int ar[], int num)
{
    ar[max];
    int i, j, temp;

    if (sizeof(ar[*size]) != max) {
        ar[*size] = num;
    }
    else {
        printf("The array is full\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `ar[max];` is pointless in `insertArray`. and `sizeof(ar[*size])` is absolutely *not* doing what you think it is; that looks like pure guesswork. You also never increment `*size` once you've set your added value.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger. Step through the code line by line. Watch the variable values, in particular the `size` variable, as the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in above code is that every function is creating it's own `ar[]` array and the original one is not affected. You should pass `ar[]` just like the way you pass `size` or alternatively you can declare both `size` and `ar[]` as global variables thus all functions can manipulate exactly the original ones without need to be passed, if you have confusion about passing addresses and pointers.

The second point is that `sizeof(ar[*size]) != max` doesn't make sense. You can use `size != MAX`, instead.

The third point is that you do not have to pass `max` to the functions, instead you can use `MAX` directly within all functions.

Finally, size desn't seem like erroneous, but if it is, you must use a debugger.